# Open XML SDK Word Processing Vertical Orientation in Table Cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml

Is anybody aware of a way I can switch the text orientation in a table cell by 90 degrees?  I am creating some label templates in Word with Open XML and some need vertical text orientation.  I am trying to apply the `TextDirection` element to the cell and it's not working...

```
var tc = new TableCell();
tc.Append(new TextDirection() { Val = TextDirectionValues.BottomToTopLeftToRight });
```

I have tried...
`BottomToTopLeftToRight`, `TopToBottomLeftToRightRotated`, and `LefttoRightTopToBottomRotated`

Am I missing something or should I be applying it in a different location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply it to TableCellProperties.

```
TableCell cell = new TableCell(
    new TableCellProperties(
        new TextDirection() { Val = TextDirectionValues.BottomToTopLeftToRight }), 
    new Paragraph(
        new Run(
            new Text("test"))));
```